# Is genetic equivalence a universal truism or are there exceptions?

Tags: genetics

Someone who I have been discussing scientific topics for some time came around to the notion that, on a biological level, the seed of a plant is not the same organism as the mature stage of the plant. When I brought up the theory of genetic equivalence he completely shut down and refused to go further. He then told me to pose the question here so here I am. To be concise "is an acorn a tree".

Answer (score 2):

**Is an acorn a tree?**

It all depends on your definition of identity. What makes two things being the same things to you? There is no "fundamental biological definition of identity". Therefore a sentence like

> [..] on a biological level, the seed of a plant is not the same organism as the mature stage of the plant

This sentence has no meaning as it wrongly assume that there is some kind of fundamental biological definition of identity but there is no such thing. Scientists are not dictators stating how things must be defined. Scientists use terms that they define that help them describe the world. Anyone is free to come up with its own definition and work with it.

Let's consider two possible questions that are better defined

**Is the genetic material found in a tree cell the same as the one that was found in the acorn before it became a grown-up tree?**

Yes for most cells you would consider and yes again but except for somatic mutations and shortening of telomeres.

**Is an acorn the same weight as a tree**

No!

So, really it all depends upon what your definition of identity is.